# RAML 1.0 types issue

Tags: raml

I have a problem with RAML 1.0 types. Validator gives me error on position: 0 and is_archive: false that integer and boolean are excepted. And that error occurs when i using traits.

```
types:
  CatalogObject:
    type: object
    properties:
      id: number
      title: string
      position: integer
      is_archive: boolean

/catalog:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          type: CatalogObject
          examples: [{
            id: 1,
            title: Simple1,
            position: 5,
            is_archive: true
          }, {
            id: 2,
            title: Simple2,
            position: 0,
            is_archive: false
          }]
```

For example:

```
traits:
  catalogItem:
    responses:
      404:
        description: 404 Not Found
```

When i removed that code, everything works fine.

Comment: Poor, general, topic line.Please, make it specific to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator I use identified a few issues with the response definition.  Once the errors are resolved the traits compile without an error.

1. `body` needs a mime-type
2. If you expect an array response, as shown in the example, the response `type` should be an array.

   `type: CatalogObject[]`
3. The `examples` keyword, if choose to use that instead of `example`, supports multiple examples so the body should be a dictionary with a key for each example:

```
/catalog:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: CatalogObject[]
            examples:
              first_example:
                [{
                  id: 1,
                  title: Simple1,
                  position: 5,
                  is_archive: true
                }, {
                  id: 2,
                  title: Simple2,
                  position: 0,
                  is_archive: false
                }]
```